# Kosher flavored beer without certification on the bottle?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, liquor-beer

I've always heard that the rule in the United States is that domestic non-microbrewery/craft unflavored beer needs no certification as kosher, as all such beers are kosher, but that any other beer (viz, foreign, microbrewery/craft, or flavored) needs certification. Apparently, that's *almost* correct: The Star-K's ["Star-K Liquor List"](http://www.star-k.org/cons-appr-liquor.htm), March 2014 edition, reads in part:

> Beer, UNFLAVORED: Acceptable WITHOUT Certification EXCLUDING when brewed in a craft, pub or home brewery that may bottle non-kosher flavored beers (Oyster, Bacon etc.) EXCLUDING English Milk Stouts
>
> Beer, FLAVORED: Requires Certification

And yet I've recently been in the homes of two different religious families, who served two different brands of flavored beer (I forget which) without certification on the label. So I'm wondering whether they simply erred, or whether there's more to it:

- Are there accepted authorities who dissent from the Star-K and maintain that flavored beer doesn't need certification (perhaps only for certain flavors or something)?
- Are there brands of flavored beer known to be under certification without its being printed on the bottles?
- Or is there perhaps some other justification?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4935

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44597

Comment: Interesting question. I was recently at an event in Denver that had about 10 Rabbanim having dinner. One of the hosts brought a sampler case of local flavored microbrewery beer, and as none of the Rabbanim objected, I assume that it was OK. I am in contact with one of them, so B"N, I'll pass this question on to him.

Comment: It's possible a hechsher was on the larger package and just not on each bottle

Comment: https://twitter.com/cholentface/status/867763613905412097