# Does flavored drip/ground coffee require a hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

It seems like plain unflavored coffee does not need a kosher certification.

Does flavored drip/ground coffee require a hechsher?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43796

Comment: Does a coffee filter (assuming a non-flavored filter)  have any halachic ramifications on the kashrut of the coffee?

Comment: Re your comment, [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From The [Chicago Rabbinical Council website](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/coffee_and_tea_pesach.php)

> A general rule in kashrus is that any item which is flavored requires
>   kosher certification whether the flavor is labeled as natural or
>   artificial, and flavored coffee is no exception to the rule.

And from the [Star-K -The Kashrus of Coffee](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-thirst-coffee.htm)

> Flavors are complex chemical products which contain various
>   ingredients, some natural and others artificial. There are more than
>   three thousand flavor ingredients to choose from in formulating a
>   flavor. Some are clearly not kosher. To complicate matters further,
>   food labels are only required to mention that flavors were added
>   without listing the specific flavor. **Based on this it is easy to see
>   why all flavored coffees must be kosher certified**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How come unflavored coffee is fine without a kosher certification?

Comment: I suggest you read the Star-K article linked above for a complete overview.

Answer (score 1):

Unflavored coffee is a fruit according to halacha, like any fruit outside of israel it does not require a hechsher ( I believe that coffee is not being grown in Israel, but if it were, it would need a hechsher for orlah, shmittah, trumah etc). However flavoring has many ingredients, a chemist for the OU Rebbetzin Leff told me coffee flavor has over 200 ingredients, which although batel in quantity to the main ingredient, cant be batel lechatchila.