# Reliable Ask-a-Rabbi Websites

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, internet

There are some times on this site where questioners will be directed to "ask their Rabbi." While it's always optimal to have such people discuss the question with *their* own Rabbi (and such action should be stressed), there are times when people either don't actually have a Rabbi [yikes], or are embarrassed to ask such questions to their own Rabbi.

What are some useful and reliable websites to get practical Rabbinic advice?

Comment: Aren't you afraid of promoting seriously non-ideal methods of getting pesak?

Comment: @Issac are websites like askmoses that bad?

Comment: @yydl askmoses, in particular, actually does not provide pesak. They are careful to only answer in general terms. For those who do, isn't it seriously non-ideal to get pesak from a rabbi who doesn't know you, via one-message-each communication? I suppose embarrassing topics could be a worthwhile area for this, given the inherent issues associated with talking to a rabbi whom one knows, and that a possible entry for that could be http://www.yoatzot.org/ask.php

Comment: @yydl I agree with you for that purpose, particularly, it's worth compiling such a list, probably actually on [main] rather than here.

Comment: @Issac Permission granted to move.

Comment: Before we get carried away with _resorting_ to innovative methods of eliciting _p'sak_ I think the emphatic pronoun in the question deserves some elaboration. Although this whole discussion is based on the famous words of _Y'hoshu'a ben P'rachya_ to "make yourself a teacher", my understanding is that we interpret this directive practically as allowing for (or preferring) making multiple decisors for oneself - to pertain to particular areas of expertise. . .

Comment: . . .In selecting one's _rav_, one considers the degree of comfort one will have in asking for practical advice from that person. If that threshhold is reached for most questions, but not all, then it behooves the person to find a _rav_ who is both expert and comfortable in the neglected area, without violating the aforementioned instruction.

Comment: @WAF Indeed, from personal experience there are times where the Rav himself referred me to another Rav more knowledgeable in the area at hand.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Why is this non-ideal?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146/2

Comment: @IsaacMoses - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2236/is-the-lemon-slice-added-to-a-soda-in-many-bars-a-problem-kosher-wise/2237#comment34823_2237

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36454

Comment: I think it would be important to just ask your personal Rabbi.

Comment: Mesora.org is one of the best ask the rabbi websites you could find.

Comment: similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136262/anonymous-shaila-lines

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For all *sh'eilos*, if one does not have a personal *rav*, or one's *rav* is not available, Star-K initiated the "Institute of Halacha", run by R' Mordechai Frankel of Baltimore and endorsed by [R' Moshe Heinemann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Heinemann). Questions may be emailed or called in during certain hours. See [here](https://www.star-k.org/ask-rabbi) for email address and phone number.

Comment: That's quite generous of them.

Comment: the cRc also provides such a service: http://www.crcweb.org/answers_to_shaalos.php

Comment: @curiouser perhaps add that as its own answer

Answer (score 16):

For *Choshen Mishpat* and *ribis* questions, I've had [the Business Halacha Institute](http://www.businesshalacha.com/) recommended to me. It has an ask-the-rabbi service (via e-mail or, I think, phone) it calls "Halacha Hotline".

Answer (score 13):

http://www.aish.com/atr/

http://www.dinonline.org/ask-the-rabbi/

http://www.chabad.org/asktherabbi/default_cdo/jewish/Ask-the-Rabbi.htm

Comment: Din Online is from one of the best. They have an amazing group of Talmidei Chachamim there to help with all the shailos.

Answer (score 12):

The Chofetz Chaim Heritage Foundation has a number you can call with halachic questions relating to sh'mirat halashon, or proper speech.  It's 718-951-3696, and it's available from 9:00 p.m. to 10:30 p.m.

Comment: Hello G Moses, and welcome to Judaism.SE! Thanks for the topic-specific recommendation.

Comment: Is that eastern time? (I'm guessing, based on the area code.)

Answer (score 10):

In Israel, there are a few resources. [Eretz Hemdah](http://eretzhemdah.org/qna.asp?PageId=3) is one in English and they refer difficult questions to senior poskim.

Comment: Personally I've had trouble understanding the English in some of their replies in the past; maybe it's a lost-in-translation thing.

Comment: I work at Eretz Hemdah and would be happy to clarify if something is not clear.

Answer (score 5):

- [Rabimeir.com](http://www.rabimeir.com) (you can go to the [Shu"t section](http://rabimeir.weebly.com/151314931514.html) on the menu - but you have to ask in Hebrew) - HaGaon HaRav Meir Eliyahu Shelit"a
- [Doresh-tzion.co.il](http://www.doresh-tzion.co.il) (you can go to shu"t behalacha section on the side menu - but you have to ask in Hebrew) this is the Q&A of HaGaon HaRav Bentzion Mutzafi Shlit"a (a Posek)
- [Kisse-r.co.il](http://kisse-r.co.il/) - Answered by staff members at the esteemed Kisse Rahamim Yeshiva in Bene Berak headed by HaGaon HaRav Meir Mazuz Shelti"a (a Posek); occasionally he will answer the questions.

Answer (score 5):

- http://www.aish.com/atr/ask/
- http://www.askmoses.com/
- http://www.asktherabbi.org/ - this is from gateways and they're usually fast and reliable
- YU has something for YU/RCA rabbis called http://www.Rabanan.org which has a very thorough responsa feature.

Comment: As noted [above](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/reliable-ask-a-rabbi-websites#comment10532_8303) askmoses.com does not provide pesak, only general answers.

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to ask in Russian, both halacha and hashkafa, as well as personal relationships (updated on 2021-03-24):

- [www.toldot.ru](https://toldot.com/) - Toldot Yeshurun, a network of very knowledgeable Russian rabbanim, including R' Asher Kushnir and R' Reuven Kuklin. They also often bring in family psychologists to answer the questions as well. They guarantee your question will be addressed by someone.
- [www.evrey.com](https://www.evrey.com) - R' Eliyahu Essas
- [Atlanta Russian Jewish community](http://www.evreyatlanta.org/ask.aspx) - R' Isroel Zelman, seems to me that all questions are answered as well, sometimes with a slight time delay.
- [www.istok.ru](http://www.istok.ru) - R' Chaim Burshtein, Chief Rabbi of Lithuania
- [imrey.org](https://imrey.org/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83/) - R' Reuven Kuklin, Israel (could not easily find how to ask a question though)

Comment: Thank you for these additions.  Do you have personal experience with these sites?  Do you read Russian?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, I have experience with the first two, and know R' Zelman personally, as well as some rabbeim from Toldot, as well as some talmidim of R' Essas... Russian is my mother tongue...

Comment: Great, thanks for the further information!

Comment: Worth noting that when I click the link to evrey.com, it takes to me the webpage for target (the store). When i type in evrey.com into the browser, it does work.

Comment: @Binyomin thank you, corrected

Comment: @Binyomin used the opportunity to add a few more sites

Answer (score 4):

The THE FEDERATION OF SYNAGOGUES in the UK offers the service described at http://www.federationofsynagogues.com/askthefederation/

It says:

> Ask the Federation is a service of  the Federation Beis Din to the
>   wider kehilla.
>
> Ask your shailos in one of two ways...
>   1. ShailaText - send an SMS to 07860 017 641 for a personal response within four working hours
>
> 2. ShailaOnline - join the conversation in our growing Facebook community - post your question on the group for a response in under 24
>      hours.
>
> In memory of Dayan Gershon Lopian z"tl

Comment: SMS number has changed to +447403939613.

Answer (score 3):

http://revach.net/ask/ but they don't always answer every question.

Answer (score 2):

Halachipedia (Rabbi Yitzchok Levy of Lakewood answers questions): http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Ask_the_Rabbi

Comment: they don't have an ask the rabbi service anymore

Answer (score 2):

For Yeshivas Rabbenu Yitzchak Elchanan (RIETS/YU) alumni and RCA members only there is a very reliable responsa service on http://rabbanan.org

Answer (score 2):

There is a relatively new website (soon to be app) I set up for this specific reason (a user friendly system for a quick response to halachic or any torah questions that a Jew might have) here is a brief summary of the goals of my website:

Do these situations sound familiar?
You did not know the correct Bracha...
Your husband mixed up the milchig and fleishig dishes (again!)...
You had a question that you didn't feel comfortable asking someone who knows you... 
You feel guilty "bothering" the Rabbi with your "simple questions" all the time...

Too often, many of us will convince ourselves that we THINK we know the correct thing to do and that we are PROBABLY right.

Pocketrabbi.com is taking your Orthodox Jewish observance to the next level by making sure that you never again have to act as your own Rabbi when you don't know what to do, and that NONE of the questions that you have related to Judaism go unanswered.

check it out:

www.pocketrabbi.com

www.facebook.com/PocketRabbi

Comment: Who's the Rabbi?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The website link still goes to a "coming soon" page. It is not ready yet.

Answer (score 2):

One may ask questions of well-known dati leumi posek Rav Shlomo Aviner by emailing his assistant at toratravaviner@yahoo.com. The assistant always answers questions (after asking the question to the Rav).

Answer (score 2):

I found this which seems promising

https://www.chayimaruchim.com/contact.asp?pagetype=Rabbi

Even though they seem to imply on their site to be mostly healthcare related only, I personally called them and asked a generic halachic question about davening that had nothing to do with healthcare and the guy happily answered

Answer (score 0):

Dinonline.org

Kollel “Choshen Mishpat” was founded in 1995. The founders’ goal was to raise the public’s awareness to the Mitzvos Bein Adam Lechavero and to the Halachos pertaining to Dinei Mamonos (financial matters). At the head of the institution stand Rabbi Yosef Fleischman Shlit”a and Rabbi Asher Flegg Shlit”a. The Kollel numbers around 120 scholars, many of whom received Semicha (Halachic ordination) for Rabbinate and Dayanut both from Gedolei Yisrael and from the Chief Rabbinate of Israel. The alumni of the Kollel serve as Dayanim in Batei Dinim around the world and in the Kollel’s Beis Din.

Over the years there developed alongside the Kollel other frameworks related to these issues.

1. Beis Din for monetary matters “Nesivos Chaim”
2. Beis Hora’ah for people interested in consulting in matters pertaining to monetary and business matters is free of charge.
3. Research Institute – Which employs some of the Kollel alumni and puts out various publications.
4. “Alon Hamishpat” – Since 2006 the Kollel puts out a monthly publication with an international circulation of thousands of copies. In the publication one can find essays on current topics, practical halachos, rulings of the Beis Din and more.
5. Seminars – three times annually the Kollel conducts seminars in monetary laws.
6. Dinonline.org – the site that you are visiting right now. We hope you will enjoy it.

Comment: This was mentioned already by @GershonGold

Comment: Did you write this? "the site that you are visiting right now" huh?