# power went off Bishul Akum

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, electricity, bishul-akum

If a Jew turned on a portable burner for a non Jew to cook pancakes and the switch for power went off,but the actual metal is hot enough to cook on without any power,if the non Jew turns it back on is this a problem of bishul akum?

Is it a problem for this pancake which could be cooked without power now,and is it a problem for the next pancake which needs the power?

Comment: As long as it is still hot when the power comes back on, why isn't it like a twig in the fire?

Comment: @DoubleAA, perhaps the existing residual heat isn't fuel for the subsequent fire? (Not saying either way, it just doesn't seem obvious that it is the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All pancakes which can be cooked by heated plate are permitted, and those that require switching on plate are forbidden if the plate was switched on by a gentile.

This answer was provided by a rabbi on http://www.pocketrabbi.com, a user friendly system for a quick response to halachic or any torah questions that a Jew might have.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for this answer, as well as the useful-looking link! If you can [edit] in anything about the reasoning behind the responsum you received, that would make the answer much more valuable. You may be interested in posting an answer to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/reliable-ask-a-rabbi-websites and updating the details as PocketRabbi matures. Please consider [editing your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/4715) to give yourself a name!

Comment: I asked a big posek,he said the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Issac. I posted more details about the website to that question and i hope it helps.