# Where can I get a qualified rabbinic authority who will agree to advise over the phone?

Tags: product-recommendation

I'm in a very complicated situation which requires the advice of a competent individual. Due to the various details I need to remain anonymous. Where can I get a qualified rabbinic authority who will agree to advise over the phone?

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69909/759

Comment: Highly related. possible dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83612/8775 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34566/8775. See also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8303/8775.