# Shabbat Candles or Wine

Tags: halacha, kiddush, erev-shabbat

It is said in the shulchan Aruch that one should buy Shabbat Candles instead of Wine if one didn't have enough money for both of them. However,  When we see into the talmud it says in Shabbat 23b that a person must choose Candles because there cannot be shalom without light. But then again, we have electric lights nowadays which can also replace candles in times of need. And if someone was to talk about the spiritual lights from the candle as the Zohar talks about them, i have read that Rabbi Ovadia Yosef says that someone should not posek with regards to Kabbalistic concepts.  So then,  Should one theoretically choose wine or candles?

Comment: I am sorry but,  We don't have a Rabbi here

Comment: If you know electric lights are good halachically, and you have no idea if they're a problem in kabbalah and don't know any reason why they could possibly be a problem, then what's the question?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36454

Comment: @DoubleAA I think, or rather hope, this guy is not looking for a practical ruling. Kosher wine can be had for $5 a bottle, and candles for much less.  I think he is asking a theoretical question, but made the mistake of asking it in a way you disprefer

Comment: @RhHaokip Do the sources include mention of bread?

Comment: @SAH I have no preference other than enforcing site policy as dictated by the community. BTW how often is kosher wine available for $5 a bottle in places that don't have a rabbi?

Comment: Maybe a better starting point is whether electric lights can be used instead of candles in a pinch?

Comment: @DoubleAA Manischewitz! It's davka what you can get in places without a rabbi. PS, I edited the question; better?

Comment: I don't think anyone with Internet access, even in the 3rd world, loses sleep over 2 candles once a week as a line item in their monthly budget; this is, as @SAH stated, an akwardly worded theoretical question. Please edit and reopen.

Comment: @DoubleAA I live in a town without either a rabbi or kosher wine, we make our own grape juice, it costs around $2-$3 per family per week

Comment: @SAH the OP lives in India (per his profile) where I would assume candles are cheap and kosher wine very hard to find in most places outside of large cities. So this might be a real question - thus out of scope for MY

Comment: @mbloch i would like theoritical answers. Practical: we can make our own grape juice too