# Male equivalent to yoatzot.org

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, sexuality, men-male, niddah

Are there any [Ask-a-Rabbi websites](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8303/3073) that are geared specifically towards questions regarding Taharas Hamishpachah (i.e. marriage, sexuality, and men's health), parallel to [yoatzot.org](http://www.yoatzot.org/about.php), from which I quote:

> Yoatzot Halacha are women certified by a panel of Orthodox rabbis to
>   be a resource for women with questions regarding Taharat Hamishpachah
>   (an area of Jewish Law that relates to marriage, sexuality and women's
>   health). This role was devised to assist women who are more
>   comfortable discussing very personal issues with another woman.

Comment: I doubt there are.  The whole institution of Yoatzot was created specifically because women were uncomfortable asking these intimate questions to (male) rabbis.  A man can simply ask his rabbi.

Comment: @Shmuel Why don't you make that an answer? "Are there any...?" "No, there are not."

Comment: Because I don't know for sure that there aren't.

Comment: You could try [Puah Institute](https://www.puahonline.org/ask-the-rabbi) - they have an Ask the rabbi the service with archives available online. They normally deal with fertility issues but their rabbanim are specialized in the topics you describe