# Eating by one who doesn't separate glass

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, meat-and-milk, glass

Some, mainly Ashkenazim, hold that glass dishes must be separated between milk and meat. Some, mainly Sefardim, do not. May the former eat on the latter's glass dishes?

Comment: relevant http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/940/759

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After-the-fact, Ashkenazim rule that glass never "treifs" up food. The question is whether I may go eat at his house in the first place, is that called "choosing to use glass dishes"?

An easy way out is Rabbi Moshe Heinemann's view (shlit'a). [From the Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-containers-glass.htm):

> Q: There are many varieties of glass on the market. Do arcoroc,
>   duralex, pyrex, corelle and crystal have the halachic status of glass?
>
> A: Yes, they do.
>
> ...
>
> Q: Can one use the same glass utensil as a Kli Rishon, to cook and
>   bake both dairy and meat dishes? A: No.
>
> ...
>
> Q: Can other glass dishes, such as salad bowls or casseroles, be used
>   for both dairy and meat meals? A: If the food is cold, or the glass
>   dish is used as a Kli Sheini, it may be used for both dairy and meat
>   meals. Unless it is used on the oven or range, a Kli Sheini is okay.

In other words, even Ashkenazim may use the same glass plates, as you don't bake directly on the plate (it's used as a *kli sheni*). So you're fine unless you **know** your Sephardic hosts put their Corelle plates in the oven, or use the same Pyrex baking dishes for both meat and milk -- unlikely.

Comment: Why would it be unlikely that Sefardim would use Pyrex baking dishes interchangeably?  Are there other factors?

Comment: I meant it's unlikely that you would know that they use Pyrex interchangeably. It wouldn't surprise me if many Sephardim don't do so, due to Ashkenazic influence; and many people have more metal/ceramic than Pyrex anyhow.

Comment: Only oven or range? What about microwave? Heating up an individual serving in the microwave isn't uncommon at all.

Answer (score 6):

http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/38/Q1/

> I spoke to Rav Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg, Zatzal, about the Halacha in
>   this case. He told me that Sephardic Jews rule according to Rav Yosef
>   Karo, and therefore use glass dishes for both meat and milk, while
>   Ashkenazic Jews conduct themselves according to the opinion of Rav
>   Moshe Isserlish, therefore refraining from the use of glass dishes for
>   both. But, he said, because there are different opinions regarding the
>   Halacha, there is room for leniency in cases where extenuating
>   circumstances exist (for instance, a Ba'al Teshuvah who is going for a
>   family visit where the kitchen is not kosher, but glass utensils are
>   used). Should such a situation arise, you should contact your LOR for
>   advice.